# Run .NET4 project on 2.0 runtime

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

We would like to upgrade our product from .NET3.5 to 4.0. But we don't control the exe's, we are just a library. The applications are created by customers. 
Is there any way that they could keep using their .NET3.5 exe's? E.g. could we create a wrapper that is .NET3.5 and internally calls our new code?

EDIT: It is not about a specific feature of .NET4. I am thinking about a migration strategy: Can we upgrade our dll's and stay compatible with old exe's?

Comment: Which .Net 4.0 features would you like to use?

Comment: What exactly do you need from .NET 4?

Comment: Personally, I do hate library vendors forcing me to upgrade my app. In fact one reason I cannot use the latest DevExpress components in our commercial products.

Comment: @UweKeim It's a bit of a mixed issue - I also hate when vendors won't upgrade to a new framework, even if it would provide *significant* benefits.  (I agree, though, that forced upgrades for no reason are horrible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use your library, the executable will (typically) need to be compiled as .NET 4, as well.  Without that, they will not be able to add a reference to your project.

You could, potentially, work around this via having them use your assembly via COM instead of directly referencing it, but that's going to make it far more painful to use than forcing an upgrade to .NET 4, as you'll still need .NET 4 to be deployed on the machines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep both versions: 3.5 and 4.0, letting the customer know they should consider upgrading. This upgrade should be *free* of course, to keep everyone happy (customers always like new stuff offering new features but they're most probably not eager to pay something they didn't ask for).

The next step would be to settle a reasonably far in the future deadline (again, let your customers know about it) after which the 3.5 version should be frozen: it stays as-is, existing users will still be supported but you're not going to offer it anymore to new customers *and* the 4.0 version is the one which gets the new features.

Or you simply fork the project and mantain both the 3.5 and 4.0 versions (it's up to decision makers, in the end).